# Control access to C++ global scope?

Tags: c++, c, class, scope

I sometimes have to transform some matured c source code into classes. A problem that sometimes arises is that some functions share global variables. This typically is hard to find.

I just was thinking about, if there is a possibility to disallow a class explicitly to use symbols from the global scope or anything like that. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Of course i could search for all global varialbles and transform them to class members, but that can be somewhat difficult. If the source code has some 1000 lines i can not review all the code. I just wonder, if the compiler could help me to find them.

Comment: Remove all variables from global scope ;)

Comment: hold on a moment, you are writing the classes, so you have control over what variables are used or not - so what is the problem?

Comment: The suggestion from @zerm isn't that bad. But instead of remove the variables, just comment them out, one by one. Then when you build you will get errors from all places where the variables are referenced, and you can plan better where to put the common variables (hint: `namespace` is your friend here.)

Comment: All that is right in theory, but i am looking for a more automated solution. See my edit.

Comment: As said, comment global variable and the compiler will tell you where it is used. btw 1000 lines is a big source. I am sure you are breaking some OO principles (at least KISS and one responsibility).

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR: 1 000 lines ? You can do it manually. 1 000 000 lines would be daunting, but for 1 000 you'll spend more time on the tool than on the job.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he said he is doing that kind of restructuring regularly

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the global variables in a `namespace` scope (may be more than 1). After this the compiler will complain for the ex-global variables. Just go and fix accordingly.

**Edit**: For the new question, **No** there is no facility from compiler which will single out the global variables. Moreover, finding global variables is easy and does not require code review or restructuring. It's a mechanical job. As soon as you find it, enclose it in a `namespace` scope. e.g.

```
int g_value;
```

converts to,

```
namespace Globals {
  int g_value;
};
```

Comment: Definitely more than one namespace, otherwise it's just as bad as having global variables.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't quite see the point, actually. Whatever its scope, it'll still be global and accessible anywhere...